# Non desirable ' " ' in excel sheets saved as text files

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting, save-as

I have a spread sheet with cells containing formulas in column A concatening multi-lines text and cells contents e.g.:

```
="test
list = {
    {
        obj1 = "&B1&"
        # a comment
        obj2 = 99
        # another comment
        obj3 = 3
        obj4 = "&C1&"
        obj4 = {"
```

Say B1 = "TEST", C1 = "test"

Then I copy/past by value column A in another sheet and save to .txt format - I have tried all available ones with the same result: it includes unexpected and non desired double quotation marks ' " ' at the beginning and at the end of each cell:

```
"    test
    list = {
        {
            obj1 = TEST
            # a comment
            obj2 = 99
            # another comment
            obj3 = 3
            obj4 = test
            obj4 = {"
```

Expected result is:

```
test
list = {
    {
        obj1 = TEST
        # a comment
        obj2 = 99
        # another comment
        obj3 = 3
        obj4 = test
        obj4 = {
```

When I search ' " ' in the pasted sheet, it returns none. So I conclude Excel adds quotation marks to cells contents of type string.

How to avoid it?

Comment: What are you doing with this .txt? I just want to note that it's not really uncommon for programs dealing with file format transfers to put strings in quotes. And this is a string. So, if this might not be able to be solved in Excel - what's the next thing happening with this .txt? Could the quotes be handled there? Might be a search for them & an empty replace in the .txt work?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do, but it is unpractical.